# How thymleaf submits variable from a form to controller to be attached to Url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a variable inside a form in thymleaf, The variable is a date that has to be embedded to a method in controller that will display the data for the particular date. My problem is when the variable is selected and submitted  i get a weird link in my url like this
**localhost:8080/masomo/somo/?date=11-03-2021&date=date** without any response to that particular page. What am I doing wrong on submitting the variable.

Here is the form in thymleaf in masomo.html

```
           <form th:action="@{/masomo/somo/}">
                <select id="date" name="date" required="true">
                <option value="none" selected disabled hidden > 
                    Select a Date 
                </option> 
               
                <th:block th:each="somoChagua : ${masomoChagua}">
                 <option th:each="date : ${somoChagua.date}"  th:value="${date}" th:text="${date}" ></option>
                </th:block>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" th:name="date" th:value="date" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button> 
               
            </form>
```

Here is how I set the method in controller to receive the variable

```
  @Autowired
  private MisaleRepository misaleRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/masomo/somo/{date}", method=RequestMethod.GET  )
  public String chaguaSomo(@RequestParam(value = "date", required = true) String date, Model model  ){

    List<Misale> masomo = misaleRepository.getSomoBytarehe(date);
    model.addAttribute("masomoYote", masomo);

    return "masomo";

}
```

Here is my Repository

```
 public interface MisaleRepository extends JpaRepository <Misale, String> {

     @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM misale WHERE misale.date = ?1 " , nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Misale> getSomoBytarehe(String date);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my form like below

```
    <form th:action="@{'/masomo/somo/' + ${date}}">
```

And I changed the button to

```
     <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
```

Also I changed the method in controller to

```
     @GetMapping("/masomo/somo/{date}")
     public String chaguaSomo(@RequestParam(value = "date",required = true) String date, Model model ){......}
```

After the above changes I could now pass the data from the form inside a block th:each  to the controller

Answer (score 1):

Remove `th:name` and `th:value` in the submit button line

```
 <button type="submit" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
```

The date value is passed from view to controller as request param but the controller is receiving it as path variable.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/masomo/somo/", method=RequestMethod.GET  )
  public String chaguaSomo(@RequestParam(value = "date", required = true) String date, Model model  )
```